# Ext-GWT text rotation not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I am using Ext-GWT version 3.0 (specifically 3.0.0-rc), and am attempting to rotate some text via a TextSprite. It works fine in Google Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 8.

Java source:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.DrawComponent;
import com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.sprite.TextSprite;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.Viewport;

public class TextRotation implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        TextSprite sprite = new TextSprite("Some text");
        sprite.setRotation(270);
        DrawComponent component = new DrawComponent();
        component.setViewBox(true);
        component.addSprite(sprite);
        Viewport vp = new Viewport();
        vp.add(component);
        RootPanel.get().add(vp);
    }
}
```

Using the IE developer tools to export the generated source produces the following. The text component is being created, but seems to be placed outside of the visible area:

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 1268px; HEIGHT: 785px" class=GAOO-TBDNN>  <DIV style="WIDTH: 1268px; HEIGHT: 785px" __eventBits="100">
    <DIV style="WIDTH: 1268px; HEIGHT: 785px" class=x-vml-base>
      <?xml:namespace prefix = vml />
      <vml:shape style="Z-INDEX: 0" class="vml x-vml-sprite" coordsize = "21600,21600" filled = "t" fillcolor = "white" stroked = "f" path = " m0,0 l27388800,0,27388800,16956000,0,16956000 xe">
        <vml:skew class=vml on = "t" matrix = "935375f,0,0,935375f,0,0" offset = "34468954f,52315599f"></vml:skew>
        <vml:fill></vml:fill>
      </vml:shape>
      <vml:shape style="Z-INDEX: 10" class="vml x-vml-sprite" coordsize = "21600,21600" filled = "t" fillcolor = "black" stroked = "f" path = " m0,0 l1,0 e">
        <vml:skew class=vml on = "t" matrix = "0,935375f,-935376f,0,0,0" offset = "52315599f,-34468954f"></vml:skew>
        <vml:textpath style="LINE-HEIGHT: normal; FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: ; FONT-SIZE: 12px; v-text-align: left" class=vml on = "t" string = "Some text"></vml:textpath>
        <vml:path class=vml textpathok = "t"></vml:path>
        <vml:fill></vml:fill>
      </vml:shape>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; LINE-HEIGHT: normal; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; FONT-STYLE: normal; FONT-FAMILY: null; LETTER-SPACING: normal; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; TOP: -10000px; FONT-WEIGHT: 400; LEFT: -10000px"></DIV>
```

If I then comment out the line "sprite.setRotation(270);" the non-rotated text displays fine. The generated HTML is exactly the same as above, except for the values for the "skew" entries. Diffs as follows:

```
10c10
<         <vml:skew class=vml on = "t" matrix = "935375f,0,0,935375f,0,0" offset = "34468954f,52315599f"></vml:skew>
---
>         <vml:skew class=vml on = "t" matrix = "1510899f,0,0,1510899f,0,0" offset = "1445363f,14325573f"></vml:skew>
14c14
<         <vml:skew class=vml on = "t" matrix = "0,935375f,-935376f,0,0,0" offset = "52315599f,-34468954f"></vml:skew>
---
>         <vml:skew class=vml on = "t" matrix = "1510899f,0,0,1510899f,0,0" offset = "1445363f,14325573f"></vml:skew>
```

Googling, examining past problems on the Sencha forums and here gives me no clues.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion: not many folks here are going to know GXT 3 yet since it isn't released. I'd post this in the sencha forums. Also, `rc2` was released a few days ago which has a large number of bugfixes from rc1.

Comment: Travis - thanks for that. I have already posted this to the Sencha forums - no replies yet :-( I have also since updated to rc2. This has not changed the behaviour.

Comment: Update: Sencha just informed me that it appears to be a bug and they have opened a new bug in their system: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196734-TextSprite-rotation-not-working-in-IE8